# Regular Expression to split by VbCrLf + ignores VbCrLf within double quotes. VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

Still trying to understand Regex.
I need to split string on VbCrLf, but not when they are inside double quotes.

So my String is built using stringbuilder like below:

"ABCDEF"
"This is
SampleText"

So I get that into IO Stream and parse it. In IO stream, I get a single string to parse like
"ABCDEF" vbCrLf "This is vbCrLf SampleText"

Now I convert IOStream to string and want to split this.
So required output is

"ABCDEF"
"This is SampleText"

(If possible also explain me the expression, so I can understand and modify as per my needs)

Thank you

Comment: How do you put a `CrLf` inside of double quotes?

Comment: Are you saying that "VbCrLf" is your delimiter you want to split around in your string?  As DonA said, how exactly are you containing a CrLf inside double quotes?

Comment: yes CrLf is demiliter. Basically, the text box is multi-line. which has demilimiter as new line. But it still is one value. So values which are multi-line are considered one value which still have CrLf

Comment: Can you provide some example strings or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

I think it would be easier to simply use a regex matching routine which will then output each line. This regex will:

- assumes `\r\n` is equivalent to VbCrLf
- matches entire lines and text
- trims the delimiting `\r\n` to mimic how the split command would drop the delimiter
- keeps quoted strings together even if the quoted string contains a `\r\n`

`^(?:[^"\r\n]|"[^"]*")*(?=\r\n|\Z)`

[image]

## Example

[Live Demo of the Regex](http://fiddle.re/tua0a)

**Sample Text**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3 "this is 
line 3a
line 3b
line 3c" and some more text
line 4
line 5
```

**Code**

```
VB.NET Code Example:
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("^(?:[^""\r\n]|""[^""]*"")*(?=\r\n|\Z)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Matches Found**

```
[0][0] = line 1
[1][0] = line 2
[2][0] = line 3 "this is 
line 3a
line 3b
line 3c" and some more text
[3][0] = line 4
[4][0] = line 5
```

Comment: My String is
"ABC" VbCrLf "This is VbCrLf SampleText"
Expected result is:
ABC
This is  SampleText

The result I get from above regex is
""
" "This is  SampleText""

Comment: These comments don't really do a good job with expressing formatting. Can you update your original question to show exactly what you're looking for to include sample input text, desired output and what you've already tried?

Comment: Got it. It is working as expected. Thanks. I should be passing single double quotes and it was considering as two different strings. My bad. Thanks! It works as expected.

Comment: It worked for \r\n but strange that it doesnt work for comma(,). I replaced \r\n by , and it doesnt work. The logic will still stay same, but the character it is looking will change. When replaced \r\n it just grabs the first word before comma.

Comment: By replaced you mean `^(?:[^"\r\n]|"[^"]*")*(?=\r\n|\Z)` becomes `^(?:[^",]|"[^"]*")*(?=,|\Z)`. To make this work you'd need to also replace the leading `^` anchor with `(?<=\A|,)` see also: http://fiddle.re/tua0a

Comment: Looks like you have mastered this Regex man.. you Rock! Thanks a lot.